# What happen to file we downloaded in bluestack?

Tags: apk

I go to bluestack. I download some files some apk.

Then what?

How can I install that apk?

I click an icon that looks like a down arrow and nothing happens

Comment: Please add more detail to your question, like what you are trying to download, BlueStacks configuration info, etc. Screenshots of what you have tried may be helpful as well.

Comment: apk files. The down arrows can be pulled down. However, it seems that we cannot install apk using files we download straight to bluestack.